# data in onchange to be moved/passed to onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an on event in input type file i do it like this

```
$("#image").on("change", function(e) {
    var name = $("#filename").val();
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var filename = name.length > 1 ? name  : file.name;
        var filetype = file.type;
        var filesize = file.size;
        var datafile = {
            "filename":filename,
            "filetype":filetype,
            "filesize":filesize
            };
        console.log(datafile);
        console.log(file);
});
```

also i have an onclick event where i have an ajax that send data to a php file where i save the information

i do it like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  var id= $('#id').val();
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var address= $('#address').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../include/save.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        address: address
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

    }

},
error: function(data) {
    alert('Error! ');
}


});});
```

i want to add the data in onchange in onclick so i can save the image or pdf file in database.How can i use the data on onchange event?I mean how can i be able to access the data in onchange event from onclick even? How is this possible any idea is appreciated

`UPDATE`

html

```
<input type="file" id="image" accepts=".pdf" />
<input type='text'  id="filename" name='filename' maxlength="15" value="" class=' InputBoxF'/>
```

Comment: can you post your html too ? have you try with the change event on your input type file ?

Comment: i am getting the result i want sir @kevpoccs what i want is to put that result in onclick that will save the data in database

Comment: i think the function must be write in php

Comment: Which element has id `add`..some kind of submit button?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar yes it is a submit button when i click it all data will be passed to my php file where i save them

Comment: @HogRider Do you find something wrong with my solution proposed..?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar as i read here as well someone mention that it is not a good practice to use global variables..im sorry but i cant accept something like that..please correct me if i am wrong and your fiddle is having this `Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined`

Comment: @HogRider I am not at all using global variables...I am passing data through events..Do check again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your variables in the outer scope from both functions to make them defined in the functions.

```
(function(){

var file, filename, filtype, filesize, datafile;

$("#image").on("change", function(e) {
    var name = $("#filename").val();
        file = e.target.files[0];
        filename = name.length > 1 ? name  : file.name;
        filetype = file.type;
        filesize = file.size;
        datafile = {
            "filename":filename,
            "filetype":filetype,
            "filesize":filesize
            };
        console.log(datafile);
        console.log(file);
});

$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {

    // Here you can access the variables now

  var id= $('#id').val();
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var address= $('#address').val();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../include/save.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
          id: id,
          name: name,
          address: address
      },
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);

      },
      error: function(data) {
          alert('Error! ');
      }

  });

});

})();
```

However you may have to check in the click-handler if the variable has a correct value

**EDIT:**
Fixed your ajax-code
Added self-invoking function

Comment: is there no other way?making the variable global is not a good idea right?

Comment: You don't have to make them global. Use a self-invoking function as container: (function() { //code })() - this way your code is separated from the global scope

Comment: can you show the self invoking function in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Fuzzyma, one solution could be to make global variable. What i want to propose is, passing `data` using `custom events`. I have made a simple fiddle to explain the concept and used a dummy data to be passed. Take a look at below fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/da833p6j/1/

```
$("#image").on("change", function(e) {
//DummyData
var datafile = {
        "filename":'xyz',
        "filetype":'txt',
        "filesize": '2KB'
        };
 var e = $.Event("passData");
//Trigger the custom event along with the dummyData
$(this).trigger(e,[datafile] );
});
$(document).on('passData', function(e, param){
   //Attaching passed data to DOM Element
   $('#filename').data('someData', param);
});
$('#add').on("click", function(){
  var fileData= $('#filename').data('someData');
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '../include/save.php',
  dataType: "json",
  data : fileData,
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

  },
  error: function(data) {
      alert('Error! ');
  }

  });
});
```

To know more about `custom events` in jquery, you can checkout this link [CreateEvent](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: Why you would use an event when you can pass the data directly to the element?

Comment: @Fuzzyma Because making everything global is not a right solution for sharing data generated from one DOM node and to be used by another DOM node...

Comment: neither is triggering an event and listening to that event only to pass data to the element which you could do directly instead of triggering the event. Btw: I never mentioned any global scope on my answer. I spoke about the outer scope!

Comment: @Fuzzyma Just tell me for a situation where data generated on some event handler, for which you have no idea at start point ..So at that point, Will you still be able to create "global" variable for that..In this case, you have created these many variables `var file, filename, filtype, filesize, datafile;` only because you have a prior info....